# Search specific value and take count in unsorted data in linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a file which has the data as below :

```
1,20160507057,VBATCH_20160507_00001,1000,GGG,OR1,20160507,ATP,VS12,TEST,Ver,

2,AVAILABLE,20160507T13:23:19,ver,,

2,USED,20160507T16:45:00,,12394301044,803123123314626251006

1,20160507331,VBATCH_20160507_00003,1000,GGG,OR1,20160508,ATP,Pure,vour,Test,

2,POP,20160507T16:10:27,ver,,

2,AVAILABLE,20160507T16:17:42,ver,,

1,20160507441,VBATCH_20160507_00003,1000,GGG,OR1,20160508,ATP,Pure,vour,Test,

2,POP,20160507T16:10:27,ver,,

2,AVAILABLE,20160507T16:17:42,ver,,
```

The records are starting with the first line :

```
1,20160507331,VBATCH_20160507_00003,1000,GGG,OR1,20160508,ATP,Pure,vour,Test,
```

This are the sub lines for the record above :

```
2,POP,20160507T16:10:27,ver,,

2,AVAILABLE,20160507T16:17:42,ver,,
```

So for every starting line there will be some lines following it , so my requirement is I need the below values :

The last line for a record which is ending with available i need all those data's and the second column(first line) of that record

example :

```
1,20160507331,VBATCH_20160507_00003,1000,GGG,OR1,20160508,ATP,Pure,vour,Test,

2,POP,20160507T16:10:27,ver,,

2,AVAILABLE,20160507T16:17:42,ver,,
```

The above records only i should consider .

Output :

```
20160507331  Available
```

Comment: Please use [edit] to make this post human readable!

Comment: what u dint understand tell me ... 

For every long line data records i have some lines following it ... 

In that if the end of the line has only AVAILABLE I need those records only.

Answer (score 0):

create file : test_script.py

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    last_id = None
    last_value = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('1,'):
            if last_id != None and last_value == 'AVAILABLE':
                print last_id, last_value
            last_id = line.split(',')[1]
        elif line.startswith('2,'):
            last_value = line.split(',')[1]
    if last_id != None and last_value == 'AVAILABLE':
        print last_id, last_value
```

then run cmd: `python test_script.py your_file_path`

I hope it can help you.

Comment: can u give me full script , its python ?? dint get you ... can u explain me .. if i get full script i can run ..

Comment: Your output came which all has the 2nd column value in first line and second line and third line second column :

20160507057 AVAILABLE
20160507057 USED
20160507331 POP
20160507331 AVAILABLE
20160507441 POP
20160507441 AVAILABLE





But My requirement was which 1st line is ending with available value at the second line .. i need only those records ..

20160507331 AVAILABLE
20160507441 AVAILABLE

Comment: kevinlu,

I need some more values from the 1st line :

1,20160507331,VBATCH_20160507_00003,1000,GGG,OR1,20160508,ATP,Pure,vour,Test,


DESIRED OUTPUT :

20160507331,VBATCH_20160507_00003,OR1,20160508

Answer (score 0):

```
source=$1

while read line
do

column_width=$(echo $line |awk -F, '{print NF}')

if [ "$column_width" -eq 12 ];then

grep  -A2 `echo  $line` $source|tail -1 |grep -q  AVAILABLE
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then

id=$(echo $line |awk -F, '{print $2}')
echo "$id AVAILABLE"
fi

fi

done < $source
```

Use it like:

```
./script FileName.txt
```